# Furnace return sucking in drafts throughout home

Tags: hvac

Why would it be that when the furnace blower is running, cold air is being sucked into the house from every nook and cranny, in all rooms? 832 sq ft old home with downflow furnace on main level flowing to partial basement. Single 14x20 return vent is high on wall in main living area adjacent to furnace/closet. I actually weatherstripped the bedrooms and bath to stop some of this and the rooms are now warmer (is that bad?) Do I need an additional return vent somewhere? May be limited there on possible areas of placement. Could the blower fan speed need adjustment? This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Check that you don't have leaks in the furnace ducting which delivers heated air back into the house. If it's blowing that out somewhere (attic/basement) then that 'lost' air has to be made up somehow.

Comment: All combustion type furnaces need air to burn fuel.  On most newer homes they have an inlet to bring in outside air to the burner.  Guess where old homes get their inlet air, by sucking the air in though cracks/nooks and crannies.  Adding a pipe from the outside to in front of the burner should reduce it.

Comment: Could be leaky supply ducts that is pumping heated air into the attic or crawlspace.   Very energy inefficient, if so, that air needs to be replaced and that could be the reason.  Best would be to inspect the supply ducts for leakage or even breakage.   If soft ducts, rodents can do a lot of damage to them.

Comment: How many CFM is the Fan ? If it is adjustable, them adjust the fan speed. You ducting system is unbalanced, the fan is sucking more then blowing

Comment: 832*8=6656 Cubic feet room volume.  With air return of 14x20 you get 730 CFM air flow capacity. 730*60 = 43000 CFH. That would be equal to 6 air exchanges per hour for your home. More than enough to heat or cool the room. Actually it says your are about twice es fast as normal, saying your air return is doing to much

Comment: does it happen when the blower is running but the furnace is not calling for heat?  if the pilot is the only thing lit and the burners are not going but the blower is running then it should have no effect on pressurization of the house.

Comment: It only happens when the blower is running, not when pilot light is only lit. 

These are fantastic and super helpful comments all. I appreciate it so much. Now I have an idea of where to go with this ridiculous problem I’ve been living with for 5 years. Additional inputs welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. There are two different airflows moving through a forced-air fuel fired furnace.

- Flow #1:  Combustion air.  This is taken from ???? (we'll come back to this) and ventilated out an exhaust stack outside the house, to protect you from carbon monoxide and other exhaust products.
- Flow #2: The air being heated.  This is taken from your duct returns, and given back to you heated via your duct system.
- Flow #3: The wind, which has nothing to do with your furnace.  It's trying to get from one side of your house to the other side. It uses every available path including poorly sealed doors and windows.

Flow #2 should be neutrally balanced within the house. It should not cause drafts from outside.

Flow #1 is a wildcard.  Some of the newest furnaces actually have *a concentric* exhaust flue [with an inner and outer pipe](https://youtu.be/QrlSt0SvOXQ?t=407).  The inner pipe carries the exhaust outward, and the outer pipe carries in air from outside that will be used for combustion.  Aside from protecting your house from the hot exhaust, this does another neat trick: it transfers almost the heat from the exhaust into the incoming combustion air. Which increases the efficiency of the unit.   this type of double-flue design means that combustion air does not cause drafts from outside.

However, if you have the older type, which has a simple stack, where does it obtain the air to burn in the burner? *Well, from the heated air inside your house!* So when it ejects hot exhaust air out the stack, all that air has to be replaced by new air coming into your house from outside. This happens through the various and countless air leaks found in older homes. And yeah, that'll cause drafts, but they shouldn't be noticeable.

Note that modern homes are so well-sealed that "ejecting type" devices like old furnace flues, dryers, bathroom vents and kitchen vents must be carefully designed so that they don't "draw a vacuum on the house" and cause exhaust gas to flow the wrong direction down an old style furnace or water heater flue, causing combustion products to be sucked into the house.

Now the last one is wind.  And that has nothing to do with your furnace*.   The wind will just blow into any leaks or lack of sealing in any window, door, soffit or wherever, and create noticeable drafts.  This is alarming because all the air blowing in at this end of the house, is being blown out at the other end of the house - and you're paying to heat that!

You can tell whether this is going on just by stepping outside and just standing there and feeling for what the wind is / wind chill is like.   If the air is dead calm, then the drafts are not that.

* except that if it's raining, your house's skin will be subject to "wind chill" effects from that rain evaporating in the wind, which will make the house feel colder and the furnace work harder.

Comment: Amazing comment. Yeah although we get wind here, I don’t think it’s that. I have a 16-month old gas furnace but not a high-efficiency. Had I known it would help (or had they even thought to explain) I may have likely sprung for the additional cost now that I actually know something about that. I have been working on locating the drafty areas of air infiltration, including placing plastic (Velcro type) over the fairly new “sucky” windows as well :(. 2 windows to go.